# Matters the Prophet is purposely leaving out

Tags: supernatural

In the TV series *Supernatural*, [S04E18, "The Monster at the End of This Book"](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/The_Monster_at_the_End_of_This_Book), Cass says that, "These things that he is writing would one day be known as God's word" but later in the same episode the Prophet of the Lord says that, "I have not written about Sam's drinking of Demon blood".

My question is, what is purpose and sense of having a prophet of the lord - who is meant to write God's word down when he is not actually doing the whole job. At last we will end up with incomplete content, secrets and part's of God's word that are not known at all.

Comment: Keep in mind he didn't actually _know_ he was a prophet until after the whole demon blood thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your question makes a major unfounded assumption that all prophets *before* Chuck Shurley faithfully wrote down 100% of what they foresaw. If that were the case, prophecy would be a lot more clear. :)

Chuck wrote down the things he saw that he felt were most important and relevant. His "job" was to spread God's message to future generation, not to be a historically accurate secretary. We know that Chuck left a lot of details out of the books he published, including things as simple as Sam and Dean's last name, because they didn't seem relevant to the message.

Hiding the fact that Sam was doing something seemingly evil does seem like "cheating" a bit. If we accept that he is a prophet, though, we also need to accept that God is the one guiding his judgement in what is important and what is not.

Of course, all of that ignores the revelation about Chuck in the fifth season finale, which basically makes the entire discussion irrelevant, that:

> Chuck is actually the incarnation of God on Earth.

Comment: Do you have a source for that last spoiler you throw there? I saw the that episode and ending was left open to intepretation.

Comment: Officially there is no confirmation either way; it's clear that they are *hinting* at one particular interpretation, though others are possible. The only real source is something the actor who played Chuck was told by others on the staff, which he talked about at one of the conventions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ni7uidj9Rx8

Comment: @DVK: just FYI -- moot *is* a verb, but neither of us actually used it correctly. :)